# Can Rational Root Theorem be used on a polynomial in the field $\mathbb Z_7$?

Tags: polynomials, roots

I have a polynomial $[4][x]^{40}+[10][x]^{20}+[46][x]^{2}+[2],$ and I need to show that it has no roots in $\mathbb Z_7.$ I've already solved this problem; **I want to know if I can use RRT to solve it.** If I could, my process would be to test for the values $x=\pm1$ since they are the only non-fractional rational roots from the theorem.

If I can't use RRT, over what fields can I use RRT on polynomials? What properties must hold so I can use RRT?

Comment: $x^2 + x + 1$ has no rational roots. What happens $\pmod 7 \; \; ?$

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use RRT here. RRT refers to rational solutions of polynomials with integer coefficients, but the "integers" mod 7 is the entire field! In general you want to use RRT when your field is the field of fractions of an integral domain (you probably also want it to be a P.I.D.?)

Answer (score 1):

There is a general form of the rational root theorem which holds over any UFD. Namely, let $R$ be a UFD and 
$$
f(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_1x+a_0\in R[x].
$$
If $K$ is the fraction field of $R$ and $f(k)=0$, with $k=\frac{p}{q}\in K$ for $p,q$ coprime, then $p|a_0$ and $q|a_n$. The proof follows in the exact same fashion as for the integers: write 
$$
a_n(p/q)^n+\dots+a_1(p/q)+a_0=0,
$$
multiply through by $q^n$ to get 
$$
a_np^n+\dots+a_0q^n=0,
$$
and then reduce mod $p$ and mod $q$.

Unfortunately, despite the generality of the rational roots theorem, it doesn't tell us much when $R$ is actually a field. Because then $K=R$ and $p$ will always divide $a_0$, and $q$ will always divide $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

"Yes".  But, ..., this is a field.  *Every*(nonzero)*thing* divides $[2]$ and likewise for $[4]$, so you have to check every residue by this method.

For instance, "everything divides $[2]$":\begin{align*}
    [1][2] &\cong [2]  \\
    [2][1] &\cong [2]  \\
    [3][3] &\cong [2]  \\
    [4][4] &\cong [2]  \\
    [5][6] &\cong [2]  \\
    [6][5] &\cong [2]
\end{align*}

So a plain lifting of the rational roots theorem to this setting means you have to check every possible fraction of elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$, which is every element of $(\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z})^\times$.

How has this improved the situation?

There seems to be a misunderstanding:  The rational roots theorem isn't helpful for finding roots of a polynomial over a field.  It's helpful for finding roots in the field of fractions of a ring.  In the usual presentation, the ring is the integers and the field of fractions in the rationals.  Since the field of fractions of a field is just the field itself, this sort of theorem can't help you at all for polynomials over a field.  In short, to have a useful rational roots theorem, the ring of coefficients must *not* be a field.

Having said that, the question is how much less than a field can we go and still get the proof of the RRT to work?  While I haven't worked through all the details, I'm pretty sure this will work for a UFD ([unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain)), but not for a mere ID ([integral domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain)).  I do not know if some structure intermediate between those is the sharp dividing line between a working RRT analogue and a non-working RRT analogue.